# How to Add Child Record to Existing Parent Record?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-model

I've been googling and scouring Stack Overflow for some sort of hint on this subject but the information is scattered at best.

I'm trying to Create a new Child Record (`Comment`) and save it to an existing Parent Record (`Post`).  I am using Ember-Model, rather than Ember-Data, but any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

At the moment, I've been successful creating a new, embedded `Comment` but **only** when it is created with a *new* `Post` record.  So:

**How do I go about loading/retrieving the currently loaded `Post`(parent record) in order to apply `Comments` (child records) to it?**

I've been reading up on controller dependencies, using `needs:` and `this.controllerFor` and `this.modelFor` in order to have access to another controller/model's `content` but have been unable to wire these things together into something meaningful.

Anyway, here is what I've whittled my application code down to, in the hopes I might be able to stumble into the proper way of doing this...

#### Routes

```
    App.Router.map(function() {
      this.resource('post', { path: '/:post_id' }, function() {
        this.resource('comments', { path: '/comments'} );
        });
    });
```

I removed all the other resources & routes, so I'm left with `App.Post`, `App.PostIndex`, and `App.Comments`.  I think my routes are the issue here, I assume I'm not properly implementing the methods to use the loaded `Post` record in my `Comments` route.

```
    App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function() {
        return App.Post.find();
      },

      setupController: function(controller, model) {  // I'm not certain if this
        controller.set('content', model);           // setupController is needed?
      }

    });

    App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function(params) {
        return App.Post.find(params.post_id);
      },

      setupcontroller: function( controller, model) { // again, unsure if this
          this.controllerFor('post').get('comments'); // is correct.
            controller.set('content', comments);
      }

    });

    App.CommentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      afterModel: function() {
          this.set('post', this.modelFor('post'));
        },

      setupcontroller: function( controller, model) {
          this.controllerFor('post').get('comments');
            controller.set('content', comments);
        }

    });
```

#### Controller

```
App.CommentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: "post",

  actions: {

     addComment: function() {
          var post = App.Post.create({
            title: 'static post title'
          });

              post.get('comments').create({
                message: 'static message'
            });

              post.save();

      }

  }

});
```

This is my current Comments Controller, which can create a new `Post` with an embedded `Comment`.  I've found and been given numerous examples in which to create the `Comment`, but none seem to work for me.  Basically, I'm struggling with defining the `var post = ...` as the currently loaded record.  I've implemented various approaches in an attempt at trial & error.  Thus far I have attempted:

- `var post = App.Post.create();`, returns property undefined, as this would create a new record.  However, I gave it a shot as every example i saw related to this defined their record as such.
- `var post = this.get('post');`, returns a cannot call 'get' on undefined.  I've tried using this method of defining my current post on both the `Comments` controller and `Post` controller.
- `var post = this.get('controllers.post.content);`, returns a 'cyclic error' from the backend I'm using.
- `var post = App.Post.find();`, returns a cannot call 'get' on undefined.
- `var post = App.Post.find(1);`, Again, returns a cannot call 'get' on undefined.  Figured I'd give it a shot because this is one of those recurring examples people provide.  The backend I use applies its own ID to each record, and I'm unsure if I would be able to/how to have the `.find()` method use a dynamic ID value and retrieve only the model I just loaded.

I'm guessing that I'm not properly setting up my Routes and Controller dependencies?

If anyone has a suggestion, relevant link, or fix I would be very grateful.

This one (seemingly simple) issue/use case has me at wit's end at this point.

Comment: What version of Ember Data are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (works pre beta 2):

```
App.CommentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
     addComment: function() {
        this.content.createRecord({
            message: 'static message'
        });   
     }
  }
});
```

Ember Data Beta 2 and later:

```
App.CommentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ["post"],
  actions: {
     addComment: function() {
        var post = this.get('controllers.post');
        var comment = this.get('store').createRecord('comment', {
            message: 'static message',
            post: post
        }); 
        comment.save().then(function() {
            post.addObject(comment);
            // You may or may not need to save your post, too. In my case my backend handles 
            // the inverses of relationships (if existing), so there's no need. We still need 
            // to do this for Ember, though

        });      
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, is my comments route properly set up to load the current Post? Also, I'm using Ember-Model rather than data.