# Ember.js / Rails Posting Relationships to Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, coffeescript

Ok, I'm working on a simple Ember / Rails app, and I'm trying to post a hasMany association in a single HTTP request.  For what it's worth, I'm using Rails for the API.

- Ember: 1.4.0-beta.1+canary.011b67b8
- Ember Data: 1.0.0-beta.5+canary.d9ce2a53
- Handlebars: 1.1.1
- jQuery: 1.10.2

**Release Model**

```
App.Release = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  tracks: DS.hasMany 'track', {embedded: 'true'}
```

**A "Release" has many "Tracks"**

```
App.ReleasesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend

  model: -> @store.createRecord 'release'

  afterModel: (release, transition)->
    release.get('tracks').addObject(@store.createRecord 'track',{
      name: 'Track 1'  
    }).pushObject(@store.createRecord 'track',{
      name: 'Track 2'  
    })

  setupController: (controller, model)->
    controller.set('content', model)
```

Releases Controller

```
App.ReleasesNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend

  actions:{
    save: ->
      @content.save()
  }
```

How can I post the two tracks and one release at once?  I'm planning to use **accepts_nested_attributes_for :tracks** in my Rails API... but I'll be happy if I can see the Tracks in my development console for a start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Add Child Record to Existing Parent Record?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907773/how-to-add-child-record-to-existing-parent-record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working like this:

```
App.ReleaseSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend

  serializeHasMany: (record, json, relationship)->  
    key = relationship.key
    hasManyRecords = Ember.get(record, key)

    key = key+'_attributes'

    if hasManyRecords && relationship.options.embedded == 'true'
      json[key] = []
      hasManyRecords.forEach (item, index)->
        json[key].push(item.serialize())
    else
      @._super(record, json, relationship)
```

This works nicely with **:accepts_nested_attributes_for** in Rails.  Rails is expecting a hash of track models nested under the release as **tracks_attributes**.

Couple gotchas:

- Rails won't use the create action for the Child model, you'll have to put anything you wanna do to the children models in your Parent's create action.
- Remember to whitelist your children's parameters for Rails 4.  This looks like:

  ```
    def release_params
        params.require(:release).permit(:name, tracks_attributes: [:name])
    end
  ```

Answer (score 0):

'embedded' is not supported anymore in ember-data 1 beta. 
check this link to see how to create child records with using embed. Better to use

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#embedded-records

check this question to know more about creating child records in a different and better way
[How to Add Child Record to Existing Parent Record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907773/how-to-add-child-record-to-existing-parent-record)

Comment: Thanks Trajan - but "extractSingle" is for extracting records when retrieving from the server.  I'm trying to serialize a hasMany relationship for upload to Rails.  I cracked it - see my answer below.